# Choosing list with the largest value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists of numbers and I want a function to return the list with the largest number i.e with two lists `[1,2,3,9]` and `[4,5,6,7,8]`, the function should return `[1,2,3,9]`.

I know for a fact that this works:

```
a = [1,2,3,9]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
ans = [_ for _ in [a,b] if max(_) == max((max(a),max(b)))][0]
```

I know that there is:

```
a = [1,2,3,9]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
if max(a)>max(b):
    ans = a
else:
    ans = b
```

But is there a more efficient one or two line solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max function allows you to specify a key.  You can supply the two lists as a list of lists to max() and use max as the key function.  This will give yout the result with a very compact statement:

```
a = [1,2,3,9]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
result = max([a,b],key=max)
```

Comment: No need for those square brackets, `max(a, b, key=max)` works as well.

Comment: This solution works for multiple lists, hence why I'm choosing it as the answer but the answer by Bazingaa is faster for two lists.

Answer (score 9):

How about using the following without any for loop. Just compare the `max` of lists

```
a = [1,2,3,9]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
ans = (a if max(a) > max(b) else b)
# [1, 2, 3, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. Can you explain why the result isn't a tuple even though you put it in brackets?

Comment: @w it returns `a` if max(a) > max(b) else it returns`b`. A tuple is create by `(a,)` -  see [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
max([a,b], key=max)
```

The trick here is to know that the `max` function can be applied to objects which do not have a natural numerical interpretation, using a `key` function.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend numpy or pandas but your solution looks good to be honest.

Here is a numpy example (typing on phone so not tested)

```
npa = np.array(a) 
npb = np.array(b)

max_array = None
total_max = 0  # or -np.inf if you want to deal with negative numbers too
for k in [npa, npb]:
    if k.max() > total_max:
         max_array = k
```